# How to use a Linux system as a land phone

Tags: linux, phone, telephony

I have a land line connection. I would like to receive and make calls using my computer. It is a basic land line connection which also provides broadband internet. I am not asking about VoIP.

- I would like to know whether this is possible to make land line calls using my computer hardware.
- If possible, how to do that with some software or some commands?
- [This answer mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733732/2337276) a use of Asterix. Can we use it here?

Comment: Hi Indrajith, welcome to Super User! I'd like to recommend [edit]ing your question to remove the last bullet point, as that goes on the side of asking for product/hardware or learning recommendations, and could be flagged as Off Topic. If you have any questions, feel free to drop by [meta] or [chat]. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

What you need is an [FXO card](http://www.3cx.com/pbx/fxs-fxo/) for your PC. This is a PCI card with a phone socket in it, and it effectively works as a PSTN (public switched telephone network) phone on a card. You plug this into your wall socket just as you would a telephone.

Then you use PBX software (such as Asterisk) to mediate the calls. You would need a way to interact with the PBX, and this is usually done with VoIP, even if the FXO card and the headset are attached to the same machine. You would use a softphone that connects to the PBX over VoIP and then the PBX would make the ongoing call over PSTN.

You will still need a splitter.  The broadband connection needs to connect to your ADSL line directly and to the FXO card via a filtered splitter.

The advantage of this, over just plugging a hardware phone into the broadband line with a splitter, is that you get to take advantage of the features of a PBX like voicemail, voicemail to email, fax to emails. The advantages increase when used in conjuntion with an outgoing VoIP service.

Comment: FXO card is something that connects the land phone with the line? This is what my network provider gave me. We can connect phone to this and make calls.  Can I connect this directly to LAN port in my computer and use Asterix ? Image link: http://i.imgur.com/PE3idvx.jpg

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham: An FXO card is something that plugs into an expansion slot (e.g. PCIe) inside your computer. You can't connect your analogue phone socket on your wall to an Ethernet port on your computer.

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham I see below you have a notebook, so search for a USB FXO card rather than a PCI one.  There are other options than Asterisk too, so some research is warranted to find something that suits your needs.

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham More to the point, you *should not* connect the analogue phone socket to the Ethernet port by any means. Even if you cobble together a RJ11-to-RJ45 adapter it won't do what you want (because as pointed out, the necessary circuitry is different), and the moment the phone rings, you will at the very least burn out the Ethernet port because of the high-voltage surge. (The specific voltage might be different where you are located, but I think 70VAC is common for the ringer. That's way more than Ethernet is designed to use, which is +/- 2.5V.) **Just don't do it.**

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for the tip. Trying that is stupid. :)

Comment: In a modem like this http://goo.gl/hb2Q4L they have a port for FXO/FXS. I have a modem similar to this. So can i use this instead of FXO card? If how to configure it ? or test whether this is working ?

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham Please don't ask separate questions in comments. Comments really are meant to suggest improvements or request clarification on the post they are attached to. If you have a separate question, better to ask that as a separate question. Link to this question or answer in the new question if that linking helps provide context.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I am just clarifying which hardware to buy. If the modem has a FXO option i thought it might be useful.

Comment: Is there really no software to use a modem as a phone on Linux - surely that's all the OP is asking for and it's something that came with the (PCI or maybe even ISA) modem I was using under win95.  There was a soft connection to my soundblaster.

Comment: @ChrisH The OP was asking the question above in the question section.  Please don't use the comment area for discussion.  Use [chat] for that.

Comment: @Paul I'm attempting to clarify the OP's question in response to an answer that seems to suggest much more than what the OP is asking for, pointing out that they're after something that's old hat and just needs a modem.

Comment: You can hook up a regular phone hand set in two ways: 1) to the phone port of the splitter, to make regular phone calls (no voip), or 2) to the FXO port of the ADSL modem, if present, to make voip calls through the voip server (e.g. asterisk) in the modem. With option 2, usually the ADSL modem has a second cable to the phone port of the splitter, to allow "regular" phone calls between the handset at the FXO port and the splitter like in option 1. But if you are not interested in voip, why use the FXO port at all? All easy things can also be done complicated :-)

Answer (score 14):

The simple answer is no, you cannot make a typical computer into a PSTN-connected PBX without a new piece of hardware: an "[FXO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_service_(telecommunications)#Foreign_exchange_office) card". An analog modem cannot perform as a voice-service FXO as they are designed only to process data bits asynchronously (i.e., [V.92 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V.92)) – that's why modems are much cheaper and more common than FXO cards. A LAN card's port doesn't accept analog signaling at all and cannot handle your telecom's line voltage either, so don't plug a phone line into it!

In my opinion, if you are dealing with fewer than four telephone lines coming into your premises, I would not build a PC-based PBX but rather buy a smaller embedded device to interface with it.

The Linksys SP3102, for example, will handle one phone line, and allow you to make or receive calls with it via a desktop SIP app.
Bought second-hand, it is cheaper than many quality FXO cards, which you would need to build an Asterisk or FreeSWITCH PBX yourself. I have never used a USB-FXO, but I doubt call quality or latency will compare favorably to a dedicated PCI card (remember those things?).

Also, the time to set up and debug Asterisk/FreeSWITCH to work reliably with any FXO card is substantial, whereas the Linksys box can do basic call processing by itself after configuring it via a web page. Later on, you can integrate it with a separate Asterisk server if you want more configurability or voicemail storage, etc.

Comment: Thank you for participating on Superuser. Your answer seems thorough, however, I removed the TLDR; phrase from your answer. It is not necessary when answering a question to include acronyms and/or colloquialisms that may not be understood by readers if they do not add value to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No additional hardware is no problem if your computer (modern notebook?) has a microphone and speaker. However, to reduce or avoid crosstalk, an earphone plugged into the audio out connector would help.

There is plenty of software that can connect your microphone and speaker to asterisk, e.g.: Ekiga, Linphone.

You don't like VoIP, but you call over voip without noticing. Remember, internet started with a digital modem over phone lines, but nowadays analog phone calls are routed over the internet. Asterisk is your friend here.

Comment: Its a modern notebook. I dont think its possible to connect landline directly to my computer. But I have an option to connect LAN cable though, which is slightly bigger in size.

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham That won't work; the signalling circuitry in an Ethernet port is not able to modulate/demodulate voice signals (in most cases).

Answer (score -2):

Landline and internet. Do you mean `ADSL` over a pair of copper wire with also `POTS` telephone service? With a `splitter` to connect a regular telephone set and also the ADSL modem/router?

Most older notebooks had a RJ11 phone connector for the build in dial in modem, but most recent notebooks lack these. But even with this connector, you cannot use the notebook as a POTS telephone set.

Why not use a regular telephone and plug it in the splitter? Why insist on using a computer instead?

Comment: If i want use a regular telephone with a splitter i wouldn't have asked this question.